# windows user folder if application is run from server

Tags: java, windows

What is the best way to create file in user folder? Application is saved on server at shared place but file must be stored in computer they use. They run this application from different computers but all have Windows installed (xp and 7).

My current method looks like this:

```
public static String getDocumentsFolder() {
    String myDocuments = null;
    try {
        Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg query \"HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Shell Folders\" /v personal");
        if (p.waitFor()==0) {
            InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[in.available()];
            in.read(b);
            in.close();
            myDocuments = new String(b);
            myDocuments = myDocuments.split("\\s\\s+")[4];
        } else {
            //nothing for now...
        }
        myDocuments+="\\MyApp";
        new File(myDocuments).mkdirs();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        ErrorHandler.handle(e);
    }
    return myDocuments;
}
```

Help is much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use System.getProperty("user.home")